# Listening for input state changes from a GPIO input port on Android 6.0

Tags: android, gpio

I have an Android app that runs on a platform board with Android OS version 6.0 (Marshmallow). In the app I need to listen for input state changes on a particular GPIO port. To do this in Android 8.0 onwards Android provides Android Things APIs (https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/gpio#input-state). Could someone please help me understand how this can be done on Android 6? Some samples will help.

Comment: You should reach out to the manufacturer of any platform board for hardware related SDK/documentation.

Comment: I know that I need to listen to the GPIO 7 at /sys/class/gpio/gpio7. Question is how do I read this port from my android app. Do I need to use NDK?

Comment: Yes. You'll need to write C code to access the port. Given that you are using an older Android version I'm not sure if there is a security issue accessing the port, i.e. require System level rights/permission for app/component access which the ODM should provide info on.

Comment: It is a customised Android OS that I am using and the app is made a system app having the necessary access rights. Do you have a sample code which does something similar if not the same thing.

Comment: I am able to read the GPIO high and low values from Android source code without the use of NDK. But it is not in a callback, rather on a read basis. Even if I use NDK I believe it will be on a read basis and not in a callback. Please correct me if i am wrong here.
I need to figure out a way to read the pulses in a callback on Android 6. Is there a way?

Comment: Seems you should poll state of GPIO in a loop and if it changed create "event"  (e.g. broadcast or callback) with new state of pin.

Comment: Do you have a sample code for the same?